# Roman Numeral Conversion in Java

Tags: java, roman-numerals

I have designed this by using the stack data structure (similar to balanced parentheses problem) checking if the previous element is decreasing the number or not.

```
package test;

import main.algorithms.RomanConversion;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RomanConversionTest {

    RomanConversion romanConversion;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        romanConversion = new RomanConversion();
    }

    @Test
    public void testRomanConversion(){
        Assert.assertEquals(154, romanConversion.convert("CLIV"));
        Assert.assertEquals(101, romanConversion.convert("CI"));
        Assert.assertEquals(43, romanConversion.convert("XLIII"));
    }

}




package main.algorithms;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;

public class RomanConversion {

    public HashMap createMap(){
        HashMap<String, Integer> romanMap = new HashMap<>();
        romanMap.put("I" , 1);
        romanMap.put("IV",4);
        romanMap.put("V" ,5);
        romanMap.put("IX",9);
        romanMap.put("X" ,10);
        romanMap.put("XL",40);
        romanMap.put("L" ,50);
        romanMap.put("XC",90);
        romanMap.put("C" ,100);
        romanMap.put("CD",400);
        romanMap.put("D" ,500);
        romanMap.put("CM",900);
        romanMap.put("M" ,1000);

        return romanMap;
    }


    public int convert(String letter) {

        int result=0;
        HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map = createMap();
        String str;
        char[] array = letter.toCharArray();
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();

        for(char c: array){
            if(stack.isEmpty()){
                result += map.get(String.valueOf(c));
                stack.push(c);
            }else{
                char lastElement= stack.peek();
                if(map.containsKey(lastElement+""+c)) {
                    result -= map.get(String.valueOf(lastElement));
                    result += map.get(String.valueOf(lastElement) + String.valueOf(c));
                    stack.push(c);
                }else{
                    result += map.get(String.valueOf(c));
                    stack.push(c);
                }
            }

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd create the romanMap in the class constructor, so it's only created once.  Call the createMap method from the class constructor.  And yes, the map result would be a class variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your code is - in general - good. Your algorithm is working correctly and I really like the idea of using a Hashmap to save the values of the roman numbers.

---

One thing I miss is the handling of edge cases. Especially you should think about the following edge cases:

- letter == null
- Empty String
- Strings that aren't valid roman numbers (for example "IXI" or "MMMM" aren't valid)

The first two problems are pretty easy to solve:

```
if(letter == null || letter.equals("")) {
        return -1;
}
```

The third part is a bit more difficult to solve:

```
if(!letter.matches("M{0,3}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$")) {
        return -1;
}
```

As you can see, you can use a regular expression to validate if the string `letter` contains a valid roman number (as explained for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/267405)).

---

One thought about your testing-class: You are using `JUnit`, which is good, but I think you are testing much too little (remember the edge cases!).

I wrote a test myself with the following values:

```
String[] input = {null, "", "I", "V", "XXXIII", "DCCXLVII", "CMXXIX", "MCCXXXII", "MMMCMXCIX", "MMMMXI", "KMXI", "VX", "VL", "VC", "VD", "VM","LC", "LD", "LM", "DM", "IL", "IC", "ID", "IM", "XD", "XM", "CXLV", "MIXI", "IXI", "MXIII", "MMMM", "IIII"}; 

int[] expectedOutput = {-1, -1, 1, 5, 33, 747, 929, 1232, 3999, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 145, -1, -1, 1013, -1, -1};
```

Comment: "MMMM" is 4000, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: No, MMMM is not valid because in roman numbers there are only three same letters in a row allowed.

Comment: So what is 4000?

Comment: Well, 3999 is the highest roman number if you follow these strict rules!

Comment: Fair enough, I assume the Romans had some way around that

Comment: There is no strict rule like "only three same letters in a row allowed". `IIII` and `XXXX` are completely valid representations of 4 and 40. And there have been historical cases of 5 and even 6 written as `IIIII` and `IIIIII`.

Comment: Well, when you are using the widely used "subtractive" notation (IX = 9), it just doesn't make sense to say VIIII = 9, because it is longer than IX and it just doesn't make sense to have more than one representation for one number. Also, the Romans themselves started pretty early to write IX instead of VIIII, although I have to admit that these conventions were used widely but not universally.

Answer (score 1):

#### Technical

- The local variable `String str` is never used eirhin method `convert`. So can be removed.
- Since the map is not supposed to change, make it a `static final` field, initialized directly or in static constructor.

#### Stylistic

- Central method not only *converts*, rather than *parses* a string representation (using a predifined rule set/grammar). So would  rename it to more expressive `parseRomanNumeral` or `parseToInt` or similar.

#### Current Approach: Add Values & Undo

You are using the concept of a **lookup-table** implemented as map of symbols. This solves mainly the translation of roman symbols to arabic numbers (note: *whole number values* that can be added; not *single numeric digits* that represent an 10-based exponential magnitude).

The fact that two sorts of *special numbers* (i.e. 4, 9; 40, 90; 400, 900) can be represented by two symbols is solved by the **stack memory structure** that allows to memorize the last character (single push and pop, stack size = 1). This memo will serve like an **undo operation**, that will reduce the running sum by its previous addition in order to correctly add the *special number* (e.g. if signaling `V` translated to 5 then previously added `I` translated to 1 will be subtracted, in order to add 4).

That 2 data-structures (*map* and *stack*) used by 2 behavioural concepts (*lookup* and *undo*) form the "meat", whereas iterating char by char, adding translated values left as the "bones" (algorithmic skeleton).

The stack is not needed since all symbols of the input string can be accessed by their position in char-array.

#### Alternative: Grammar for Calculating Numbers

What if you think of [roman numerals](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) as a, numerical system, formed by a **grammar** for **calculating** numberical values, which form the *vocabulary*:

1. The vocabulary of roman symbols (`I`,`V`) can be translated to numbers (1, 5).
2. The grammar consists of rules for *adding* (`III` = `1+1+1`) or *subtracting* (`IV` = `-1+5`) values.
3. each symbol belongs to a **group of unit or magnitude** (ones 10^1, hundreds 10^2, thousands 10^3) wich require to be in a **specific sequence** in order to form a *valid* roman numeral. Generally from higher to lower magnitude (e.g. `MCDVI`), except the special cases of powers-to-4 (e.g. `CMIV`).
4. Dependent on the symbol's valid position within its magnitude the mathematical operands are evaluated (either plus or minus).
5. There is also a limit of maximum consecutives for each symbol, = 3 (e.g. `III` for 3, but not more, because 4 is `IV`)
6. Iteratively translated symbols may be used to build a valid **mathematical sum-expression** (e.g. `-100 +1000 -1 +5`).
7. The resulting sum will be the finaly parsed integer (e.g. 904).

#### Edge cases

Validation is done by rules inherent to the roman numerical system (some explained above).
There is also a symbol for zero : `N` used standalone.